# Why does my View not update in Angularjs on click, though I am able to get the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <button ng-click="removeTask(task.id);">remove</button>
      <div class="content">{{taskId}}</div>
  </div>
<div>


var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [{id:1,'name':'test1'}, {id:2,'name':'test2'}, {id:3,'name':'test3'}];

  $scope.removeTask = function(taskId){
    alert("Task Id is "+taskId);
  };
}
```

The content I get in alert needs to be put in div, but the div won't get updated, what am I not doing correctly?

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PSz7t/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want id of task - task.id. taskId is just name for function parameter, it's undefined outside this function.

```
<div class="content">{{task.id}}</div>
```

But I suppose, best practice would be to pass whole object to click function:

```
  $scope.removeTask = function(task){
      alert("Task Id is " + task.id);
  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PSz7t/3/

Comment: I need the content too in my div, see my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PSz7t/4/
sorry for miscommunication.

Comment: the whole point of my question is to get content from function removeTask, onclick and update view, and not to set the way you did it.

Comment: "Task Id is" string should come from removeTask function.

Comment: You should change scope variables in your function if you want to see that changes in view - http://jsfiddle.net/PSz7t/6/

Answer (score 0):

There different way's how you can achieve what are you looking for.
Here is mine. Since you need write an 'alert' for each removed item you need to save the status for each item so you can decide to show the alert or not

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <button ng-click="removeTask(task);">remove</button>
      <div class="content"> <span ng-show="task.status=='deleted'">Task Id is {{task.id}} </span> </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PSz7t/9/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{id:1,'name':'test1',status:'active'}, {id:2,'name':'test2',status:'active'}, {id:3,'name':'test3',status:'active'}];

  $scope.removeTask = function(task){
      task.status='deleted'; 
  };
}
```